# Haskell generalizing problem (involving list comprehensions)

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Let's say I want to know all the points on a `(x, y)` plane that are in the rectangle `has`.

I can calculate that using List Comprehensions, this way:

```
let myFun2D = [(x, y) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]
```

Now, if I want to accomplish the same for a `(x, y, z)` space, I can go the same way and do:

```
let myFun3D = [(x, y, z) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2], z <- [0..2]]
```

Is there a way to generalize this for any number of dimensions? If yes, how?

```
let myFunGeneralized = ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, because `[(a,a)]` and `[(a,a,a)]` etc are of different types, you can't write one function to represent all of them.

Anyway, in general you could use

```
Prelude> let x = [0..2]
Prelude> import Control.Applicative 
Prelude Control.Applicative> (,,) <$> x <*> x <*> x
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2),(0,2,0),(0,2,1),(0,2,2),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,0,0),(2,0,1),(2,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,0),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)]
```

If you want an `[[a]]` instead, there is a very simple function for this:

```
Prelude> sequence (replicate 3 x)
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

or (thanks sdcvvc)

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> replicateM 3 x
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

Comment: So, as there are instances of Eq defined for tuples up to 15, it shouldn't be that difficult to make your function work.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, but one still needs to write 15 different implementations for list of tuples.

Comment: Sequence as a permutation operator: that is just so elegant!

Comment: @Paul Johnson: I would call it cartesian product operator rather then permutation operator ... but yes, it is really elegant. :)

Comment: `sequence (replicate 3 x)` can also be written `replicateM 3 x`

Answer (score 2):

The list to tuple problem could be handled with Template Haskell like this (running `ghci -XTemplateHaskell`):

```
> import Language.Haskell.TH
> let x = [0..2]
> let tt n l = listE [tupE [[|l!!i|] | i <- [0..(n-1)]] | l <- sequence $ replicate n l ]
> $(tt 2 x)
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
> $(tt 3 x)
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2),(0,2,0),(0,2,1),(0,2,2),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,0,0),(2,0,1),(2,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,0),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
myFun :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -- Param: number of dimensions
myFun dim = snd $
  until ((== 0) . fst) --recursive build your tuple
  (\(d,lst) -> (pred d,[x:l|x <- [0..2],l <- lst]))
  (dim,[[]])
```

This will give you a list of point lists, you can assume that all these sublists have the same length. It should work like this:

```
> myFun 0
  []
> myFun 1
  [[0],[1],[2]]
> myFun 2
  [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

Comment: The first implementation contained a bug, (I did `(dim,[])` instead of `(dim,[[]])`), but now it works.