# Arbitrary input sets in list comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, ghc

How do I in Haskell use arbitrary input sets in list comprehensions?

I will give you an example of what I'm after:

```
generate :: [[[Integer]]] -> [[[Integer]]]
generate a = [ result | 
      i1 <- a !! 0,
      i2 <- a !! 1,
      i3 <- a !! 2,
      i4 <- a !! 3,
      ...
      i99 <- a !! 99,
      let result = [i1,i2,i3,i4, ..., i99],
      isCorrect result
   ]
```

Comment: Wait, wat? What do you want? Your example is just a really verbose way to slice and filter.

Comment: @delnan No. I can see how one would think so at first sight though. What I want is more akin to a search of all possible permutations of a matrix.

Comment: Found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742235/haskell-generalizing-problem-involving-list-comprehensions

Comment: There is a very clear difference between (i1 <- a !! 0) and (let i1 = a !! 0). Also note that a !! 0 gives a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `a` is guaranteed to be of length 100, I think what you want is `generate a = filter isCorrect $ sequence a`.  Here `sequence` is being used in the `[]` monad to produce the Cartesian product of a list of lists.

Comment: Very, very compact code. I think I will learn to love the newly found sequence function! Thanks.